# How to get a full information about amd GPU in Windows

Tags: python, gpu

**Hi,there**

I need to see something about my gpu, e.g :
fan speed
usange
voltage
and so more

I have a RX vega  11 and I'm using windows10

I've tried using pyadl with fllowing code :

```
from pyadl import *
ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()
device.getCurrentCoreVoltage()

device.getCurrentEngineClock()
```

but i'm geting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    device.getCurrentCoreVoltage()
NameError: name 'device' is not defined
```

*can anyone help me :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:
For the following methods, device is an instance of ADLDevice.
it looks like You need to declare device as one of the items returned from

```
 ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()
```

here is a snippet from the docs that might help:

```
 devices = ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()
            for device in devices:
                print("{0}. {1}".format(device.adapterIndex, device.adapterName))

                coreVoltageMin, coreVoltageMax = device.getCoreVoltageRange()
                print ("\tEngine core voltage: {0} mV ({1} mV - {2} mV)".format(device.getCurrentCoreVoltage(), coreVoltageMin, coreVoltageMax))
```

as you can see, declaring the specific device seems to be required.